# be the hospital in ten minutes

Tags: idioms

This is from a TV show.

Dad and son are going to the hospital. Dad says,

> Relax, be the hospital in ten minutes.

How can "be the hospital" be possible? It's so strange to me. Is it substandard or just colloquial?

Comment: Are you sure he doesn't say "be _at_ the hospital"? (Obviously it's colloquial speech and he has omitted "We'll".)

Comment: In order to be the hospital, you'd have to somehow convert your entire body into a medical centre. Your own organs would be each ward. It would be horrendous, and difficult to achieve in only ten minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you’ve missed something here.

Just saying *Be the hospital in 10 minutes* doesn’t make any sense.

I think they said *Relax, **we’ll** be **at/in** the hospital in ten minutes.*

Or, there could have been a mistake in the script.

Comment: Sometimes subtitles have mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct that "Relax, be the hospital in ten minutes." is nonsensical, and it should be "Relax, we’ll be at the hospital in ten minutes."

However, if this is a high stress situation (for example, a situation that would necessitate driving a child to a hospital), then it's possible that the father is really talking to himself or no one in particular.  In that case, he could be omitting some words or mumbling them under his breath.  The end result would be a sentence that everyone understands to be "Relax, we’ll be at the hospital in ten minutes.", but he might not have actually said "we'll", and "at" could be contracted to just the "t" (resulting in "beat"), or omitted altogether.